# Queries are too slow; prefetch_related not solving the problem

Tags: python, django, query-performance, prefetch

We are using Django 2.1 for [Speedy Net](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net). I have pages which display about 96 users per page, and for each user I want to display how many friends he has on Speedy Match, with an active email address. The query checks for each user if `(self.email_addresses.filter(is_confirmed=True).exists())` is true:

```
def has_confirmed_email(self):
    return (self.email_addresses.filter(is_confirmed=True).exists())
```

For each user of 96 users, it checks all his friends and runs this query - more than hundreds of times per page. The query for fetching the users is `User.objects.all().order_by(<...>)`, and then for each user it checks this query:

```
qs = self.friends.all().prefetch_related("from_user", "from_user__{}".format(SpeedyNetSiteProfile.RELATED_NAME), "from_user__{}".format(SpeedyMatchSiteProfile.RELATED_NAME), "from_user__email_addresses").distinct().order_by('-from_user__{}__last_visit'.format(SiteProfile.RELATED_NAME))
```

I added `prefetch_related` in the User's manager model:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    from speedy.net.accounts.models import SiteProfile as SpeedyNetSiteProfile
    from speedy.match.accounts.models import SiteProfile as SpeedyMatchSiteProfile
    return super().get_queryset().prefetch_related(SpeedyNetSiteProfile.RELATED_NAME, SpeedyMatchSiteProfile.RELATED_NAME, "email_addresses").distinct()
```

But adding "email_addresses" and "from_user__email_addresses" to `prefetch_related` doesn't make the page load faster - it takes about 16 seconds to load the page. When loading the page without checking if each friend has a confirmed email address it takes about 3 seconds to load the page. Is there a way I can load all the email addresses of the users once and not each time a user is checked? Actually I would also like the friends query to be loaded once and not 96 times per page (once for each user), but the page loads in 3 seconds so it doesn't matter that much. But if I could query the friends table once it would have been better.

The queries are caused by the following line ([link](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/master/speedy/match/accounts/models.py#L227)):

```
if ((self.user.has_confirmed_email()) and (step >= self.activation_step)):
```

This is called by `is_active_and_valid` which is called by `get_matching_rank`, to check if the user is a match of the specific user. This is called by method `get_friends` in the model.

**Update #1:** If I change to `return True` in `def has_confirmed_email(...)` in the model, the page loads only 3 seconds faster (13 instead of 16) so there might be more performance-related issues in this page.

If I disable the functionality of `get_matching_rank` and replace it with a plain `return 5`, the page loads much faster. But of course we need the functionality of this function. Maybe we can just cache for a few minutes the results of this function when called for sets of two specific users?

**Update #2:** I want to add a boolean field to the user model, which will be true if the user has a confirmed email address. And this field will be updated each time an email address is saved or deleted. I know how to override the save method, but how do I update this field when an email address gets deleted? It may also be deleted by the admin.

I think I should use signals such as `post_save` and `post_delete`.

Comment: Would it be better to implement some sort of cache or intermediate storage for this?  You're asking alot of the db for this, and might be time to look at alternatives for this type of data

Comment: @Jason Yes I agree, an email address may be confirmed or deleted, these are the only times when the value of `has_confirmed_email` would change. There is no way to cause a confirmed email address to become unconfirmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a field to the User model:

```
has_confirmed_email = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And the method:

```
def _update_has_confirmed_email_field(self):
    self.has_confirmed_email = (self.email_addresses.filter(is_confirmed=True).count() > 0)
    self.save_user_and_profile()
```

And:

```
@receiver(signal=models.signals.post_save, sender=UserEmailAddress)
def update_user_has_confirmed_email_field_after_saving_email_address(sender, instance: UserEmailAddress, **kwargs):
    instance.user._update_has_confirmed_email_field()


@receiver(signal=models.signals.post_delete, sender=UserEmailAddress)
def update_user_has_confirmed_email_field_after_deleting_email_address(sender, instance: UserEmailAddress, **kwargs):
    instance.user._update_has_confirmed_email_field()
```

And in the User model:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if ((self.is_staff) or (self.is_superuser)):
        warnings.warn('Can’t delete staff user.')
        return False
    else:
        self.email_addresses.all().delete() # This is necessary because of the signal above.
        return super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

I also removed the friends count from the admin view, and now the admin view pages load in about 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

For the prefetch to have any effect you would have to be using it on the User model - it's hard to tell if you're doing that from what you've included.

Without prefetching friends for each user doing `self.friends.all()` is going to cause a query. To get around the query using prefetch you could do one of the following:

```
User.objects.prefetch_related('friends')
```

Or you could use a `Prefetch` object to further filter:

```
User.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
    'friends',
    queryset=Friend.objects.filter(is_confirmed=True)
)
```

A `Count` annotation using the filter keyword argument is going to be much quicker.

```
from djang.db.models import Count, Q

qs = User.objects.annotate(
    friend_count=Count('friends', filter=Q(friends__is_confirmed=True)
)
```

Comment: The email address check has to be from code because it checks other things too, such as matching between users. But only the email addresses are retrieved from the database.

Comment: I want to retrieve all the email addresses of the relevant users once from the database without changing the code.

Comment: A friend can't be confirmed but each email address can be confirmed or unconfirmed.

Comment: @Uri hard to tell without seeing your models but I'm guessing a friend is linked to an email address? In that case in your `Prefetch` object you can filter the queryset with `.filter(email_address__is_confirmed=True)`

Comment: For each user I can query the email addresses in `(self.email_addresses.filter(is_confirmed=True).exists())`, but I want to fetch all the email addresses once and not once for each user. A friend is a user.

Comment: You can see the models on GitHub: https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/master/speedy/core/accounts/models.py

Answer (score 1):

> But adding "email_addresses" and "from_user__email_addresses" to `prefetch_related` doesn't make the page load faster ...

That is because `self.email_addresses.filter(is_confirmed=True).exists()` doesn't use the prefetched `QuerySet`.

To use the prefetched `self.email_addresses`, filter in memory:

```py
def has_confirmed_email(self):
    if self.email_addresses.all()._result_cache is not None:
        return any(email_address.is_confirmed for email_address in self.email_addresses.all())

    return (self.email_addresses.filter(is_confirmed=True).exists())
```

Note: If not prefetched, then the improved implementation still hits the database on every `has_confirmed_email` function call since the `.filter` still creates a new `QuerySet`. To handle this, make `has_confirmed_email` a Django `@cached_property`.

## Explanation

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related:

> *Remember that, as always with `QuerySets`, any subsequent chained methods which imply a different database query will ignore previously cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh database query. ...*
>
> ```py
> >>> pizzas = Pizza.objects.prefetch_related('toppings')
> >>> [list(pizza.toppings.filter(spicy=True)) for pizza in pizzas]
> ```
>
> *... The prefetched cache can’t help here; in fact it hurts performance, since you have done a database query that you haven’t used. So use this feature with caution!*

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thank you. But I already added `has_confirmed_email` as a field in the database. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Actually, `return any(email_address.is_confirmed for email_address in self.email_addresses)` can work anyway, whether or not the query is prefetched.

Comment: Yes, I saw your answer after I posted (I typed my answer, had to step away, and then posted hours later). This answer solves the original problem in the question (Queries are too slow; prefetch_related not solving the problem), while your answer achieves your end goal (make the page load faster) in a very different way.

Comment: Although `return any(...)` can work whether or not the query is prefetched, it incurs a performance cost — loading all `email_addresses` into memory — vs `.exists()`.

Comment: There should not be more than 5 email addresses for a single user so I think it should take about the same time in both ways. But if the email addresses are prefetched for many users at once, it would be faster to use it.